# What is Quine’s Confirmation theory?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method, quine

I have just read that Quine relies on his confirmation theory to establish if a scientific theory is “valid” or not. But I am not sure to have understood what is Quine’s confirmation theory and why Quine adopts it.

Comment: Some reference ? I'm not so sure that there is a Quine's theory of [Confirmation](https://www.iep.utm.edu/conf-ind/#H3). See also [Quine : Underdetermination of Theory by Evidence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine/#UndeTheoEvidIndeTran).

Comment: They might be referring to Quine's [confirmation holism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_holism), which is not the same as confirmation theory. It generally a helps to give a more precise statement, reference and some context to get good answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Quine thinks that humans as a group can "confirm" one another's findings. His view resembles, in some sense, the old idea of *summa ratio*. That the truth builds up over the generations. On the other hand, it is based on his common sense type attitude to science and not an apodictic attitude of certainty with respect to either intellect or the senses. Whereas he moves between logic and experience without favoring the one or the other. And, likewise, with his "theory" he does not go too far towards the empiricists nor towards the rationalists. That is, towards the sheer empiricism of the principle of induction, or the wild certainty of an *a priori* logical certainty.

Comment: +1 Well said : GLT

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, Kat

A useful account - no more than that - is to be found in Paul T. Sagal, 'Paradox, Confirmation and Inquiry'. I'm going to draw on three extracts from this article to throw light on Quine's theory of confirmation.

## Confirmation - the easy view

> A theory is confirmed if the positive evidence for it is sufficient. One
>    theory is more highly confirmed than another if the quality and/or quantity
>    of its positive instances is superior to that of the other. This all goes smoothly.
>    Of course we still need to explain notions like quality of positive instance
>    itself, but we expect to have little difficulty. (Paul T. Sagal, 'Paradox, Confirmation and Inquiry', Philosophy, Vol. 51, No. 198 (Oct., 1976), pp. 467-470: 467.)

In fact we have difficulties aplenty from Hempel's ravens paradox to Goodman's paradox  of 'grue' emeralds. Such paradoxes are the background to Quine's account of confirmation.

## Quine and confirmation - natural kinds

> [Quine] ... attempts to explicate *positive evidence* in terms of
>    *natural kinds*, *similarity*, and *innate quality space*. The idea is roughly that
>    positive evidence involves entities belonging to some natural kind. The
>    members of a natural kind share among themselves the relevant *similarity*
>    relation. What is recognized as natural kind is a function of the innate
>    quality space of the organism. The hard data for the last statement depend
>    in turn upon the response patterns to stimulation of such organisms. These
>    patterns tell a tale; and the term *innate quality space* is the title Quine gives
>    to the tale. Green emeralds form a *natural kind*. An individual green
>    emerald is positive evidence for the 'theoretical' claim *All emeralds are  green*. Grue emeralds do not form a natural kind. Evolution makes it
>    reasonable to identify the natural kinds we identify with the natural kinds
>    *in rerum natura*. In short, Quine suggests that confirmation theory must
>    go beyond logic and class (set) theory. It requires a theory of kinds. (Kinds
>    are neither sets nor (intentional) properties.) (Sagal: 468-9.)

(Goodman's *grue* = X is *grue* if and only if X is examined before time t1 and is green OR X is not examined before t1 and is blue.)

## Natural kinds a halfway house

> Quine concedes that the notions of *similarity* and (*natural*) *kind* form
>    something of a halfway house, or perhaps, a detour. In the more developed
>    fields of knowledge, e.g. chemistry, physics, what counts as a *kind* depends
>    not upon our aboriginal space, but rather upon chemical and physical
>    theory. We are then left in such cases with the problem of explaining
>    theoretical knowledge. Reflections on induction give rise then to reflections
>    on *similarity* and *kind* which in turn lead us to the general question of
>    scientific knowledge. But this is where we began, isn't it? For this is the
>    overall problematic situation or context outside of which the confirmation
>    paradoxes do not amount to very much. *Kind* is introduced to clarify the
>    paradox situation. *Kind* is tied originally to our primitive dispositions
>    to respond to and distinguish among various stimuli, and to a world in
>    harmony with these dispositions - such harmony being explicable in terms
>    of Darwinian natural selection. As we as individuals and as a race develop,
>    this mechanism retreats in significance. As far as theoretical science is
>    concerned, it is almost completely in the background. What then becomes
>    of *similarity* and *kind*? It is at this level that Quine brings Goodman's
>    notion of entrenchment into the picture. An *entrenched predicate* is roughly
>    speaking the linguistic counterpart of a natural kind. Quine puts the matter
>    as follows: 'A theoretical kind need not be a modification of an intuitive
>    one. It may issue full-blown, without antecedents; for instance the kind
>    which comprises positively charged particles. We revise our standards of similarity or of natural kinds on the strength, as Goodman remarks, of
>    second-order inductions. New groupings, hypothetically adopted at the
>    suggestion of a growing theory, prove favourable to inductions and so
>    become "entrenched". We newly establish the projectibility of some
>    predicate, to our satisfaction, by successfully trying to project it. In induction nothing succeeds like success.'
>
> Entrenchment at best explains why we hypothesize what we hypothesize.
>    In Peircean terms, it is part of a theory of abduction. Our theories must be
>    responsive to problems. We must make use of the most effective instruments in our arsenal. Our stocks of hypotheses and theories are such
>    instruments. They provide the instrumental context of inquiry. Like the
>    very canons of logic, they can be brought to bear in every problematic
>    situation. The entrenched predicates provide raw material out of which
>    our tools are fashioned. We would not know how to wield a strange tool-
>    one made out of unusual (e.g. grue) raw material. (Sagal: 469-70.)

## Reading

Nelson Goodman, Fact, Fiction, and Forecast, 4th ed., Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard University Press.

W.V.O. Quine, 'Natural Kinds', Ontological Relativity and Other Essays, New York: Columbia University Press, 1969.

Paul T. Sagal, 'Paradox, Confirmation and Inquiry', Philosophy, Vol. 51, No. 198 (Oct., 1976), pp. 467-470.